# How to have the two questions (strings) asked 50% of the times and randomly

Tags: java

The database is populated with 241 countries and their respective capitals. The method should randomly pick the data and it should ask about the country 50% of the times and about the capital 50% of the times. I can randomly pick the data from the list but not being able to get the questions asked 50% times each. The ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) in the if statement does not return the question 50% of the times, it varies. Need help here!

```
public String pick() {
    List<String> capitals = db.getCapitals();
    System.out.println(capitals.size());
    int n = capitals.size();
    int index = (int) (n * Math.random());
    String c = capitals.get(index);
    System.out.println(c);

    Map<String, Country> data = db.getData();
    System.out.println(data.size());
    Country ref = data.get(c);
    System.out.println(ref.toString());

    String question;
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) { 
        question = ref.getCapital() + " is the capital of?\n" + ref.getName();
    }
    else {
        question = "What is the capital of " + ref.getName() + "?\n" + ref.getCapital();
    }
    return question;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not return the question 50% of the times"? It's never going to be exactly 50% all of the time, but I don't see anything wrong with the code. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: If you run the code 5 times it could be anywhere from 0-100%, but if you run the code 1000 times it should be much closer to 50%.

Comment: Also consider instantiating `java.util.Random` to leverage convenient methods like `nextBoolean()`.

Comment: BTW, if you want exactly a 50:50 split, generate, say 5 questions of the first type, 5 of the second, then use `Random()` to shuffle the array.

Answer (score 4):

## Use *two* sources of data for exactly 50-50 results

As the Comments have said, random results will *tend* towards their odds over many events. For just a few events, you cannot predict/expect certain results.

As [commented by Ken Y-N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101206/how-to-have-the-two-questions-strings-asked-50-of-the-times-and-randomly#comment115093785_65101206), If you want *exactly* half countries and half capitals, then you need to make two collections of source data: One collection for countries, and one collection for capitals. Choose half your questions randomly from one collection, and half your questions from the other.

The [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E,E,E,E,E,E,E)) method is a handy way to produce a [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

As for your random number generator, generally best to use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). Calling the static method `current` automatically gives you a generator for use within your particular thread. And this class offers handy methods such as [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int)) with an origin and bound. For special purposes you may need a [generator that is more truly random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), but not for your situation.

```java
List < String > countries = List.of( "Brazil" , "France" , "Morocco" , "Sweden" , "Japan" , "Canada" , "Kenya" , "Spain" , "Seychelles" , "Ireland" );
List < String > capitals = List.of( "Brasília" , "Paris" , "Rabat" , "Stockholm" , "Tokyo" , "Ottawa" , "Nairobi" , "Madrid" , "Victoria" , "Dublin" );


int limit = 6; // The total number of questions we want to present to the user.
if ( ! ( limit % 2 == 0 ) ) { throw new IllegalStateException( "Must be an even number." ); }
List < String > results = new ArrayList <>( 6 );

// Countries
for ( int i = 0 ; i < limit / 2 ; i++ )
{
    int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , countries.size() ); // ( inclusive, exclusive )
    String result = countries.get( index );
    results.add( result );
}

// Capitals
for ( int i = 0 ; i < limit / 2 ; i++ )
{
    int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , capitals.size() ); // ( inclusive, exclusive )
    String result = capitals.get( index );
    results.add( result );
}

System.out.println( "results = " + results );
```

Example results:

> results = [Brazil, Japan, Japan, Dublin, Nairobi, Ottawa]

If you want to mix up the order of countries versus capitals, add this call at the bottom of the code:

```java
Collections.shuffle( results );
```

> results = [Ottawa, Madrid, Sweden, Brazil, Ottawa, Kenya]